# how to import resource file in another project

Tags: xml, maven, classpath

I am new to maven. I am migrating existing multi-level ant project to maven where I am facing a problem to call or import another projects resource. The project structure is something like below.

```
|---+- Common-Proj
|   |------ src/main/java  
|   |---+-- src/main/resources 
|       |----- resource.xml
|
|
|---+-- Web-Proj
|   |--------- src/main/java
|   |---+----- src/main/resources
|   |   |----- context.xml
|   |
|   |---+----- src/main/webapp
|   |   |--+-- WEB-INF
|   |      |-- web.xml
```

The Common proj is a simple maven project where some 3rd-party dependencies and some common api's and resources resides.

```
**The pom.xml of common-proj is something like this.**

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.common</groupId>
  <artifactId>CommonProj</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  .
  .
  all 3rd party dependencies.
  .
  .
</project>
```

The Web-Proj having the dependency of common. The pom.xml of web-proj is like this.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>com.webproj</groupId>
   <artifactId>webProj</artifactId>
   <packaging>war</packaging>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>CommonProj</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
  <build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
  </build>
 </project>
```

I am calling context.xml from web.xml, now the problem is ** I am trying to import resource.xml which is in Common-proj from context.xml file **, while starting tomcat I am getting below error.

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException:  Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:resource.xml] 
 Offending resource: class path resource [context.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [resource.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [resource.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68) ~[spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
```

I am presuming container trying to find resource.xml in the Web-Proj's resource directory. Instead it should pick from jar.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: what is the contents of resource.xml? it seems tomcat does find the file - it all looks good - but spring cannot parse the file (BeanDefinitionParsingException).

Comment: @wemu resource.xml is nothing but bean creation xml, it creates bean for all services required. It works if i put resource.xml file in Web-Proj resource directory.

Comment: is there another file read from the classpath? could you change the name for testing?

Comment: @wemu I haven't changed name.. I started freshly.

Comment: sorry what I meant was to rename your resource.xml into something else for testing. since it works in one module and not in the webmodule loading from the classpath maybe some other jar contains a resource.xml too. seems quite likely. To test that I would just choose another name.

Comment: @wemu Thanks, As you mentioned it was mistake in xml file, I mistyped  file name.